AVEVA System Platform : OCMC Log Error 80040e14 - Create instance fail to save the object one or more related objects may be in use
AVEVA System Platform 2023 - Log Error 80040e14
Create instance fail to save the object one or more related objects may be in use

Right Click over "Derived Template" then click "Validate"
after sucssfully Validation
Check out template object
then click at Check-in "Derived Template" again.
after that if you will again create the instance then you will not get the error.
